# SQL Server - Retrieve data from separate tables without using UNION clause

Tags: sql-server, join, union

I have a problem and not sure if there is even a possible solution, however still thought to raise it in this forum as there are some masters here who might be able to provide some solution :)

I have two tables - EMAIL_Request and SMS_Request. Sample data model provided below.

Email_Request

```
Seq Cust_ID  Email_ID           Sent
1    123     test@gmail.com       Yes
2    234     abc@gmail.com        No
```

SMS_Request

```
Seq Cust_ID  MobileNo           Sent
1    345     1234567890          Yes
2    456     2345678900          Error
```

**Report**

I have to show output of both the tables in one single report with mode. Sample expected report.

```
Mode    Cust_Id        Sent_To            Sent
EMAIL     123        test@gmail.com        Yes
EMAIL     234        abc@gmail.com         No
SMS       345        1234567890            Yes
SMS       456        2345678900            Error
```

**PROBLEM:**

We have in-house built reporting screen using Java-Spring/Hibernate where user can see the report. We just have to add Query in database and framework will handle the rest.

Users can dynamically add criteria in the report as well to search by Mode or Sent (status). There is a search facility on the screen to just retrieve Email records or SMS records. Also another criteria by which users can search by Sent (status).

Currently the in-house built framework simply appends the where criteria to whole query depending on user entry. Hence, I cannot use UNION clause to retrieve the report.

So, what is the best option to write a SQL query where I can retrieve the data as expected, probably using JOIN clause, but here I don't have any field that I can join between two tables and as already highlighted I cannot use UNION clause.

PS: `Seq` of both the tables are just their primary keys, so cannot be used to join.

Comment: Looks like you can use a `UNION` in a subquery, and let your framework append a `where` clause to that. Doubt it's the most efficient solution though

Comment: subquery or CTE, it's the most efficient solution I can think of.

Comment: Hi @TabAlleman.. I cannot use UNION as system will append where clause to the last query only. E.g. Sample union query will be... Select 'EMAIL' as Mode, cust_id, email_id as Sent_To, Sent from Email_Request UNION Select 'SMS' as Mode, cust_id, mobileNo as Sent_To, Sent from SMS_Request........ When user will add search criteria, then system will append where clause something like Select 'EMAIL' as Mode, cust_id, email_id as Sent_To, Sent from Email_Request UNION Select 'SMS' as Mode, cust_id, mobileNo as Sent_To, Sent from SMS_Request where Sent = 'Yes'. So no where clause for Email_Request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the reason you think you can't use UNION is because you have to write a query with only one WHERE clause, then use a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS (
Query1
UNION ALL
Query2
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
WHERE...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I think below query should solve your problem.

select * from 
(
  select 'EMAIL' as Mode, cust_id, email_id as sent_to, Sent
  from EMAIL_Request

  union all

  select 'SMS' as Mode, cust_id, Mob_no as sent_to, Sent
  from SMS_Request
) as temp
where temp..... = ...
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/143d9/2